# ActiveAdmin has_many through relationship not updating param Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, has-many-through, formtastic

I'm working through creating a has_many: through relationship in active admin.  Here are the models as they stand:

```
 class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :subcategories
 end

 class Subcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :product_in_subcategories
   has_many :products, through: :product_in_subcategories
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_in_subcategories, :allow_destroy => true

   belongs_to :category
 end

 class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :product_in_subcategories
   has_many :subcategories, through: :product_in_subcategories
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_in_subcategories, :allow_destroy => true
 end

 class ProductInSubcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :product
   belongs_to :subcategory
 end
```

In ActiveAdmin I have the permit_params and form like so:

```
 ActiveAdmin.register Product do
   # note some params that are product only have been removed for simplicity
   permit_params :name, subcategory_id:[:id], product_in_subcategories_attributes: [:id, :subcategory_id, :product_id, :_create, :_update]

     form do |f|
       f.inputs

      f.has_many :product_in_subcategories do |s|
          s.input :subcategory_id, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => Subcategory.all
      end

      f.actions
    end
end
```

The form populates as should, and will save everything except for the subcategory_id.  If I enter into the DB a proper subcategory_id the box will show checked on edit.

The messages when saving give:

```
 Unpermitted parameters: subcategory_id
```

However, it appears it is trying to submit this with the product, for which there isn't a subcategory_id.  Any ideas on what I am doing incorrectly here?  This is driving me nuts and I've read everything I can find.  I'd really like to understand what I'm doing wrong.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much time spent on this one, I couldn't find a suitable solution except for this one, which is actually very nice.  It in fact is not much different from my envisioned solution:

The only changes to the above code were made in ActiveAdmin:

```
 ActiveAdmin.register Product do
    # note some params that are product only have been removed for simplicity
    permit_params :name, product_in_subcategories_attributes: [:id, :subcategory_id, :product_id, :_create, :_update]

      form do |f|
        f.inputs

        f.has_many :product_in_subcategories do |s|
           s.input :subcategory_id, :as => :select, :collection => Subcategory.all
        end

        f.actions
      end
 end
```

Very strange how this allows a select box with no issues, but it flips out over check boxes.  Nonetheless, I'm happy with the solution.

Comment: Any solution with checkboxes?

Comment: To be quite honest, I rolled my own gem so that admin was fast and customizable with no DSL.  You can find it at [SkinnyAdmin](https://www.skinnyadmin.org).  Nothing wrong with ActiveAdmin, but the DSL is a headache to me.